# Calculate consecutive quarterly cumulative values from daily data

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
            DATE   PP
0     1964-01-01  1.0
1     1964-01-02  0.0
2     1964-01-03  0.0
3     1964-01-04  0.0
4     1964-01-05  0.0
         ...  ...
21788 2023-03-18  NaN
21789 2023-03-19  NaN
21790 2023-03-20  NaN
21791 2023-03-21  NaN
21792 2023-03-22  NaN
```

I want to calculate the consecutive quarterly cumulative values of PP form daily values

Expected result:

```
cum_start   cum_end          PP
1964-12     1965-02          25
1965-01     1965-03          30
1965-02     1965-04          12
1965-03     1965-05          11
1965-04     1965-06          25
         ...  ...
2022-9      2022-11          14
2022-10     2022-12          22
2022-11     2023-01          15
2022-12     2023-02          21
2023-01     2023-03          40
```

I tried this code but it have a problem:

```
trimestres = df.set_index('DATE').rolling('90D')['PP'].sum()
trimestres = trimestres.groupby([trimestres.index.year, trimestres.index.quarter]).tail(3)
trimestres = trimestres.reset_index().rename(columns={'DATE': 'cum_start'})
trimestres['cum_end'] = trimestres['cum_start'] + pd.DateOffset(months=3)
```

Do you have any possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can first aggregate per month with [`groupby.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), then perform a [`rolling.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.sum.html) on 3 months:

```
df['group'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.to_period('M')

out = (df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['DATE']).dt.to_period('M'))['PP'].sum()
        [::-1].rolling(3).sum()[::-1]
        .reset_index()
        .assign(DATE_END=lambda d: d['DATE'].add(2))
       )
```

Output:

```
        DATE    PP DATE_END
0    1964-01  52.0  1964-03
1    1964-02  46.0  1964-04
2    1964-03  46.0  1964-05
3    1964-04  44.0  1964-06
4    1964-05  43.0  1964-07
..       ...   ...      ...
706  2022-11  45.0  2023-01
707  2022-12  43.0  2023-02
708  2023-01  31.0  2023-03
709  2023-02   NaN  2023-04
710  2023-03   NaN  2023-05

[711 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: The code works fine when I have values other than nan (or some nan), but when I have a quarter with all nan values, the cumulative value is zero instead of nan.